# Not loading the persistence provider class in runtime

Tags: rest, jpa, jakarta-ee, jersey

I have created RestService enabled with JPA(Generic 2.0 version). Using jersey jars and hibernate entity manager jar as dependencies.

Deployment is successfull in tomcat. But when any transaction is processed, getting below exception in runtime.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

What could be the issue, not loading the persistence provider class even it is in the classpath ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with classpath? The library/jar of the Persistence Provider Hibernate and the JPA (javax.persistence) have to be in the ear/war file so that Tomcat is able to access them.
How do you create that ear/war file? With Maven? Then you have to set the dependencies at least to runtime.